# Row wise cosine similarity calculation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity

I want to calculate the row wise cosine similarity between every consecutive row. The dataframe is already sorted on the `id` and `date`.

I tried looking at the solutions here in stack overflow, but the use case seems to be a bit different in all the cases. I have many more features, around 32 in total, and I want to consider all those feature columns (Paths modified, tags modified and endpoints added in the df above are examples of some features), and calculate the distance metric for each row.

This is what I could think of,but it does not fulfil the purpose:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, (3, 5)), columns=['id', 'date', 'feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3'])

similarity_df = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x: cosine_similarity([x], df.iloc[:, 2:])[0], axis=1)
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how could I proceed with this?

Comment: Hi. What do you want to show with cosine similarity? Assume 3 versions=['v1', 'v2', 'v3] with Paths_modified=[8, 9, 1]. Which versions are the most similar? v1-v2 or v2-v3. If you use your metric, I think v1-v2 will score better than v2-v3, right? However, I think it should be the other way around. You changed a single path between v2-v3 and 9 from v1-v2. So I have doubts about the relevance of this metric but since I'm not an expert, I prefer not to post an answer :-)

Comment: No it actually does not take into account the versions at all. I have set of 35 parameters, all relating to changes that can happen within an API. Now every API has some number of commits, lets say API 1 has 10 commits, what I was essentially trying to do is, find out the cosine similarity between every commit_date, to measure if the change is close or far apart( because every commit_date is also labelled with major,minor,patch...so on) so that assists in my analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it how somehow, the loop is something I was looking for, since some of the `api_spec_id's` were not getting assigned `NaN` and the distance was getting calculated which is wrong.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# Feature columns to use for cosine similarity calculation
cols_to_use = labels.loc[:, "Info_contact_name_changes":"Paths_modified"].columns

# New column for cosine similarity
labels['cosine_sim'] = np.nan

# Looping through each api_spec_id
for api_spec_id in labels['api_spec_id'].unique():
    # Get the rows for the current api_spec_id
    api_rows = labels[labels['api_spec_id'] == api_spec_id].sort_values(by='commit_date')

    # Set the cosine similarity of the first row to NaN, since there is no previous row to compare to
    labels.loc[api_rows.index[0], 'cosine_sim'] = np.nan
    
    # Calculate the cosine similarity for consecutive rows
    for i in range(1, len(api_rows)):
        # Get the previous and current row
        prev_row = api_rows.iloc[i-1][cols_to_use]
        curr_row = api_rows.iloc[i][cols_to_use]
        
        # Calculate the cosine similarity and store it in the 'cosine_sim' column
        cosine_sim = cosine_similarity([prev_row], [curr_row])[0][0]
        labels.loc[api_rows.index[i], 'cosine_sim'] = cosine_sim
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without `apply` (faster):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, (3, 5)), columns=['id', 'commit_date', 'feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3'])


# Calculate L2 norm of features in row
df["l2norm"] = np.linalg.norm(df.loc[:, "feature1":"feature3"], axis=1)

# Create shifted dataframe
df2 = df.shift(1, fill_value=0)


# Dot product of current with previous row
dot_product = (df.loc[:, "feature1":"feature3"] * df2.loc[:, "feature1":"feature3"]).sum(axis=1)

# L2 norm product of current and previous row
norm_product = df["l2norm"] * df2["l2norm"]

# Divide and print
print(dot_product / norm_product)
```

Comment: i checked again and this metric produces bias, since for some of the rows in my df, it calculates the cosine with the 0, which produces inaccuracy. is there another way to do this without the np and using `sk.learn`?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; The goal is to determine the cosine similarity between every row that follows another in a Pandas DataFrame that has numerous feature columns. The `cosine_similarity` function from `sklearn.metrics.pairwise` may be used to accomplish this, and the new column created will contain the similarity values. To accomplish this, each successive pair of rows is iterated over, their feature values are converted to a 2D shape, and the `cosine_similarity` between them is calculated. The resulting similarity values are then put to a list and added to the DataFrame as a new column.

To get the cosine similarity between each succeeding row in your DataFrame, use the `cosine_similarity` function from the `sklearn.metrics.pairwise` package.

```py
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# Calculate cosine similarity for consecutive rows
similarity_list = []
for i in range(len(df) - 1):
    row1 = df.iloc[i, 2:].values.reshape(1, -1)
    row2 = df.iloc[i+1, 2:].values.reshape(1, -1)
    similarity = cosine_similarity(row1, row2)[0][0]
    similarity_list.append(similarity)

# Add similarity values to DataFrame
df['Distance'] = [np.nan] + similarity_list
```

The `cosine_similarity` function is used in this code to iteratively calculate the cosine similarity between each pair of subsequent rows in the DataFrame. These similarity values are then added to a list and added as a new column with the name `Distance` to the original DataFrame.

> To ensure that the feature values have a 2D shape, which is necessary for the cosine similarity function, we reshape them using reshape(1, -1).

Comment: This code works successfully for some of the cases, but in some`api_spec_id`, I have the distance being calculated in the first step itself. Is it because of the removal of `date` column or any other issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach using [`cosine_similarity`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html)

```py
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import pandas as pd

df['Distance'] = (df.iloc[:, 2:]
                    .apply(lambda row: cosine_similarity([row],
                    [df.iloc[row.name - 1, 2:]])[0][0]
                    if row.name > 0 else None, axis=1))
print(df)
```

You can also use `for-loop` but considering the size of your dataframe

```py
similarity_df = cosine_similarity(df.iloc[:, 2:])
df['Distance'] = ([None] + [similarity_df[i, i-1] for i in range(1, len(df))]
print(df)
```

**Note** If the provided code do not produce your desired output, you might have to update your question by including the exact values of the `Distance` column.

Comment: Your code won't work because it does not take into account the other columns, such as `label`, where the code runs into an error as it cannot convert string to float. I need something which only takes into account the features, but I need to retain the other columns as well, because otherwise I have no way left to map the distance back to the original df.